# Adding some config to a juniper device

Tags: python, python-2.x

I wrote this script to add some config to a Juniper device.  It works well but the whole user input validation section (yes or no section) seems a little messy.

Is there a better way I could have done it?

```
from jnpr.junos import Device
from jnpr.junos.utils.config import Config
import getpass

#Grab credentials
username = raw_input("Enter your username:")
password = getpass.getpass("Enter your password:")

#Confirmation of commands
commands = open("commands" , "r")
commands_to_commit = commands.read()
print ""
print "The commands you are about to commit are: "
print commands_to_commit
print ""
print "Do you want to continue to run these commands?"
confirm = raw_input("Y or N: ")
    if confirm in ['n','no','N','NO','No']:
            print "Exiting..."
            quit()
while confirm not in ['y','Y','yes',"Yes",'YES','n','N','NO','No','no']:
    print "Invalid Choice, Try again"
    confirm = raw_input("Y or N: ")
    if confirm in ['n','no','N','NO','No']:
            print "Exiting..."
            quit()
    elif confirm in ['y','Y','yes',"Yes",'YES']:
            continue

#Open a file called swichlist which has a list of devices to modify
with open('switchlist') as infile:
    for host in infile:
            try:
                    print "Working on:", host,
                    #Connect to devices in switchlist
                    dev = Device(host=host.strip(),  user=username, password=password)
                    dev.open()
                    cu = Config(dev)
                    #Looks for a file named commands with the list of commands to run
                    incmd = open('commands')
                    set_cmd = incmd.read()
                    cu.load(set_cmd, format="set")
                    cu.commit()
                    dev.close()
                    print "Completed:", host
            except Exception,e: print "Error:", e
            continue
```

Comment: Please correct your indentation. The code is technically broken as posted in Rev 1.

Answer (score 1):

The confirmation prompt is a self-contained chunk of code with a specific purpose.  It deserves to be extracted into a function:

```
def confirm(prompt='Y or N: ', yes='YES', no='NO'):
    while True:
        response = raw_input(prompt).upper()
        if yes.startswith(response) and not no.startswith(response):
            return True
        elif no.startswith(response) and not yes.startswith(response):
            return False
        print "Invalid choice. Try again."
```

(Technically, this is more lenient than your original code, in that it accepts strings like `'yE'` as a yes.  I think that's OK.)

Then, in your main program, you can write:

```
print "Do you want to continue to run these commands?"
if not confirm():
    print "Exiting..."
    quit()
```

---

Any call to `open()` should almost certainly be done using a `with` block.  You wrote `with open('switchlist') as infile`, which is good.  However, you also wrote `commands = open("commands", "r")` and `incmd = open('commands')`, neither of which you close properly.  But why are you calling `incmd = open('commands')` at all, when it's just supposed to be `commands_to_commit`?

Comment: If you allow any string for `yes` and `no`, you should reject an answer which is a prefix of the longest common prefix among `yes` and `no` (and any other valid answer). Example, if `yes='fantastic'` and `no='false'`, the longest common prefix is `'fa'`, and any answer prefix of this (namely `'f'` and `'fa'`) is ambiguous, but your code will treat it as a `yes` answer.

Comment: Also note that for any string `s`, `s.startswith('')` is always true, so you treat also the empty answer as `yes`.

Answer (score 0):

If you `.lower()` the input you have to match it against less patterns.
Also a single while loop can handle all the input validation stuff.

```
while True: # repeat until input is not valid
    confirm = raw_input("Y or N: ").lower()
    if confirm in ('y', 'yes', 'n', 'no'): break
    else: print "Invalid Choice, Try again"

if confirm in ('n', 'no'):
    print "Exiting..."
    quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the first:

```
confirm = raw_input("Y or N: ").lower()
if confirm in ['n', 'no']:
    print "Exiting..."
    quit()
```

right off the bat. Just initialize `confirm` to `''`and it'll kick you into the `while` loop.

You can also move the `'switchlist'` and `'commands'` filenames to variables so they aren't hard coded. Ideally, you should move them to a config file or cli args.

Below is the updated/cleaned up version of your code:

```
from jnpr.junos import Device
from jnpr.junos.utils.config import Config
import getpass

commands_filename = 'commands'
switchlist_filename = 'switchlist'

# Grab credentials
username = raw_input('Enter your username:')
password = getpass.getpass('Enter your password:')

# Confirmation of commands
commands_to_commit = open(commands_filename, 'r').read()

print ''
print 'The commands you are about to commit are: '
print commands_to_commit
print ''
print 'Do you want to continue to run these commands?'

confirm = ''
while confirm not in ['y', 'ye', 'yes', 'n', 'no']:
    confirm = raw_input('Y or N: ').lower()
    if confirm in ['n', 'no']:
        print 'Exiting...'
        quit()
    elif confirm in ['y', 'ye', 'yes']:
        continue
    else:
        print 'Invalid choice, try again'

# Open a file called swichlist which has a list of devices to modify
with open(switchlist_filename) as infile:
    for host in infile:
        try:
            print 'Working on: ', host

            # Connect to devices in switchlist
            dev = Device(host=host.strip(),  user=username, password=password)
            dev.open()
            cu = Config(dev)

            # Looks for a file named commands with the list of commands to run
            set_cmd = open(commands_filename).read()
            cu.load(set_cmd, format='set')
            cu.commit()
            dev.close()

            print 'Completed: ', host
        except Exception,e: 
            print 'Exception: ', str(e)
            continue
```